# Slider Load is slow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a site: www.patcrawforddds.com

Its using Karma theme, which uses one of 3 sliders.  The slider is pulling in "featured posts", but these are basically some html tags and buttons.  The thing is, is that it is taking around 10 seconds to load, as you may notice.  On my end however, it takes around 4 seconds, even after clearing the cache.

Ive looked into what the footer.php file is pulling in, and its determining the page template, then pulling in the slider plugin for that page template (there are two different sliders, and the files are jquery-cycle.php and jquery-cycle-2.php), in this case, we are using the jquery-cycle.php.

Ive tried moving the script to the header to load in first (bad practice) and still loads slow.  The page template already has the html and php code to pull in the slides already, so Im just curious as of what is all going on here and how to fix the load time!

Any help debugging would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Have you had a look using pingdom's speed test?](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/evDF4f/http://patcrawforddds.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Have you had a look using pingdom's speed test?](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/evDF4f/http://patcrawforddds.com/)

Tabbing through to the "Page Analysis" tab shows me that 41% of the page load time is spent on .js assets and that only 10% is on assets from your domain. Is there any way to cut down on the external services?

You might also like to look into leveraging some caching utilities like redis, memcached, and/or apc to ease up on what you're asking of the server itself.

It's really the ad networks, that are slowing down your load time, though. 292 requests total is going to take time, no matter how you cut it.

Comment: There is wp-total-cache which is activated.  Are redis etc plugins that will benefit the load speed?  Also, is what you are saying that roughly 31% of the .js assets that are being loaded are not being used on that page?  If that is the case, there has got to be a way to only load the js files that are needed per page...

Comment: @dcook , no...31% of the assets are being loaded from external domains (which, shouldn't be an issue if they're coming from CDNs).

Comment: CDNs might deliver it faster, but it's still a tonne of JS. Hard to get around it slowing things down.

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing would be to put all the JS resources outside of the head and just above the body closing tag. This by itself will make the page render noticeably quicker.

And having 3 Css sheets is not necessary, you could put them into the html body section or make 1 stylesheet, so there is fewer server request before rendering the page.

The images can be reduced in file size as well.

Page is not responsive/mobile friendly, I would get that sorted as well, it's a business page after all.

Regards